# json decode use variable as selector in php

Tags: php, json, variables, decode

I think ham to stupid for it :) I can't figured out whats wrong. I try to search at goole for the problem but think I don't use the correct phrases ... so I hope you can help me and my brain

Problem:

```
$mydata = $data['device']['26']['state']['1'];
```

Thats my code to readout json data. all is perfect. So my only problem is

```
['26']
```

this value is in an config file which is included, how can I use for expl.

```
$id
```

instead of ['26'] ... i want a littlest flexibility in this script but can't figured out how I do this.

thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

`$mydata = $data['device'][$id]['state']['1'];`

Comment: oh man ... thanks soooo much ... tried serval combination but this I missed ... worked perfect big thanks to you ...